# Не работает onclick на блочных элементах

Tags: php, javascript, html

И так, не работает `onСlick`. Выскакивает вот такое сообщение:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Вот php код:

```
<?php
    echo "<article onclick = 'document.getElementById('myform').submit()'>
        <h3>
            {$row['name']}
        </h3>
        <p class='creator'>Создатель: {$row['creator']}</p>
    </article>"
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: А вот это у вас что такое - `{$row['name']}`, `{$row['creator']}`?

Comment: @rjhdby, у автора скорее всего представленный в вопросе код находится внутри одной-единственной PHP-строки из двойных кавычек (что, собственно, объясняет отсутствие оных при указании аргументов тегов). Такие вставки в строке из двойных кавычек в PHP интерпретируются как переменные `$row['name']` и `$row['creator']` соответственно.

Answer (score 4):

Необходимо заменить кавычки внутри атрибута `onclick` на двойные:

```
<article onclick = 'document.getElementById("myform").submit()'>
```

Или наоборот:

```
<article onclick = "document.getElementById('myform').submit()">
```

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо @terron за наводку, все стало понятнее.

В таком случае вам необходимо не только поменять кавычки, как предложил @Маким (хотя проблема замечена верно), но и экранировать их таким образом.

```
<?php
    echo "<article onclick = 'document.getElementById(\"myform\").submit()'>
        <h3>
            {$row['name']}
        </h3>
        <p class='creator'>Создатель: {$row['creator']}</p>
    </article>"
```

Но лучше так никогда не делать. Стоит разделять HTML и PHP. Как-то так

```
?>
<article onclick = 'document.getElementById("myform").submit()'>
    <h3>
        <?php echo $row['name'];?>
    </h3>
    <p class='creator'>Создатель: <?php echo $row['creator']?></p>
</article>
<?php
```